# Returning closest nearest fields after Now()

Tags: mysql

I have a query like below

```
SELECT * FROM  mdata ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), orderdate)) LIMIT 1
```

returns the Nearest - Closest Time from a DateTime field type (orderdate) and this includes fields after current time, as well. How can I retrieve the fields AFTER now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I retrieve the fields AFTER now?

This simple query will do that:

```
-- Return all rows after now
SELECT * FROM mdata WHERE orderdate > NOW()
```

If you want to return just one **after** now but not equal to now, do this:

```
-- Return first row AFTER now
SELECT * FROM mdata WHERE orderdate > NOW() ORDER BY orderdate ASC LIMIT 1
```

- [`NOW()` reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)